# Find property in an object then adding an item to it's list property

Tags: c#, list, object

I'm being super daft, and I'm looking to add a new item to a property that already exists.

Here's a very simplistic look at what I'm doing. It causes a object reference not found. What am I doing wrong?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ids = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };

            var libraries = ids.Select(id => new Library {Id = id}).ToList();

            //find the property 
            var library = libraries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 2);

            //add a title to that property
            var title = "Harry Potter";
            library.Titles.Add(title); //error here
        }
    }

    public class Library
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<string> Titles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you didn't initialize `Titles` property, `Titles { get; set; } = new List<string>();` can solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialized the `Titles` property with a list, so you can't add anything to a `null`. What you're currently doing is the equivalent of something like:

```
List<string> myList = null;
myList.Add("foo");
```

You're using a class property instead of a variable, but the issue is the same.
You need to instantiate the list before you can access it and add items to it, which can be done in one of three ways:

```
 Select(id => new Library {Id = id, Titles = new List<string>()})
```

or via the constructor:

```
public class Library
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Titles { get; set; }

    public Library()
    {
        this.Titles = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

or via the property itself:

```
public class Library
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Titles { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

I personally prefer the third option, but any of them will do.